# view the details of a netcdf file in spyder using xarray

Tags: python, spyder, netcdf, python-xarray

I open a NetCDF file using xarray xr.open_dataset in Spyder.
I would like to view the contents of the file, so I click on the file at the Variable Explorer of Spyder. It looks ugly and non-comprehensible like in this screenshot:

[image]

How could I view the contents of the file in a nice and clear way in Spyder, same as for example the Google Colab would do? Here is a screenshot of how Google Colab would show the contents of the same netcdf file:

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Spider lacks support for displaying Xarray Datasets in the object browser. Colab is using Jupyter's `_repr_html_` interface. You may try asking the Spider devs on GitHub if Xarray support is possible.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) As @jhamman guessed correctly, we don't have support for Xarray Datasets. We'll try to add support to show web content (like the one Colab can display) on Spyder next year, but I don't know if we'll have the resources for that, sorry.